# Who invented the Winter Bash hats program?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, stack-exchange-history

Hats are a really nice idea and earning one is a happy event.

Who invented the hat system?

I was wondering how they were born, and who chose their names?

Comment: Check the documentary, bilal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U

Comment: I'd start by reading [this](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. i will look into it

Comment: Some of that information might be completely ironic, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U), it started in the Stack Exchange offices, where they had a tradition to hand out special hats to acknowledge outstanding work, initially to reward developers for fixing bugs and shipping features.

[image: hatted devs ship it]

And then it spread:

- community managers get hats for answers on meta that get more than 50 downvotes
- the marketing team get hats for successful campaigns or really great tweets
- sales team gets hats for big deals

From there came [Holiday 2011 Hat Dash: The Hattening](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) on Arqade which was such a success, it spread to the whole network with Winter Bash in [2012](http://stackpromos.com/promos/12/winter-bash-2012), [2013](http://stackpromos.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013), [2014](http://stackpromos.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014), [2015](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015) and [2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good answer, to make it even better you can mention the first hats event of SE: [arqade 2011 Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) (due to its immense success, it then spread to the whole network.)

Comment: There just haven't been many [community manager hats](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/606679/community-manager-hats). In fact, I had never heard of them until I first saw the video.

Comment: @JonEricson An outrage! You'll have to work much (less?) harder for it!